# Read line seperated by space using python using stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to write a size for a input and after that enter each number seperated by space which is less or equal than the size.

Like this:

First input (length): 3

inputs: 1 2 3

This should also be converted as an integer and stored in a list

I have tried this:

```
import sys


inputs = sys.stdin.readline()

print(len(inputs))

mynumbers = inputs.strip().split(' ')

newlist = [int(x) for x in mynumbers]

print(newlist)

#print(input.rstrip(''))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without using of stdin

A first possible answer (without use of `stdin` but using `input`) could be:

```
size = int(input("First input (length): "))
print(size)
input_value = input("inputs (length): ")
mynumbers = input_value.strip().split(' ')
newlist = [int(x) for x in mynumbers[:size]]
print(newlist)
```

### Using stdin

```
print("First input (length): ")
inputs = sys.stdin.readline()
print("inputs: ")
input_value = sys.stdin.readline()
mynumbers = input_value.strip().split(' ')

# in new_list are inserted elements up to inputs value
newlist = [int(x) for x in mynumbers[0:(int)(inputs)]]

print(newlist)
```

In this case the output is:

```
First input (length): 
3
inputs: 
1 2 3 4
[1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see in the example I have selected 3 as length of the list, but I have inserted 4 elements.
In the list `newlist` there are only 3 elements because length==3.

Comment: its mandaroy for me

Comment: @tor I have tried to modified the code using `stdin`. But I don't know if thid is what you are looking for. If you want give some other info.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the size to sys.stdin.readline() to limit the input by size.

```
import sys

size = int(input())

inputs = sys.stdin.readline(size * 2)
mynumbers = inputs.strip().split(' ')

newlist = [int(x) for x in mynumbers]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this only allows for an input size of 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input from user, use `input()`, not `sys.stdin.*`.

So you can just do something like this:

```py
inputs = input().split()

nums = [int(x) for x in inputs]

print(inputs) # ['1', '2', '3']
print(nums) # [1, 2, 3]
```